# NPM - save x save-exact x shrinkwrap

Tags: node.js, npm

Estou com dúvida entre os comandos abaixo, quando usar e qual a diferença entre eles? Qual a importância do --save-exact, exatamente? Quando e como usar cada um?

**npm i meu-pack --save**

**npm i meu-pack --save-exact**

**npm shrinkwrap**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### npm i meu-pack --save

Esse é o comando padrão para instalação de pacotes por `npm`.

Como usou `--save`, ele também vai salvar isso no seu `package.json` para instalação futura:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "meu-pack": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

Perceba que ele colocou um `^` antes da versão.

### Versionamento Semântico

Os pacotes do npm usam [versionamento semântico](https://semver.org/). Nele, os softwares são versionados da seguinte forma:

MAIOR.MENOR.CORREÇÃO

Esse circunflexo `^`, ou *[caret](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004)*, diz que seu software aceita `meu-pack` com versão maior ou igual a `1.0.0` e menor que `2.0.0`.

Em outras palavras, qualquer versão mais recente de `meu-pack`, no intervalo de `>=1.0.0` e `<2.0.0`, após publicada, será instalada quando alguém executar `npm install` em seu projeto.

De acordo com o Versionamento Semântico, atualizações nos segmentos MENOR.CORREÇÃO não devem modificar a API do software. Assim, mesmo que `meu-pack` receba correções ou novas funcionalidades, seu programa continuaria funcionando normalmente, pois nada muda nas funções que você já chama.

Infelizmente, nem sempre esse *contrato* é respeitado.

### npm i meu-pack --save-exact

Supondo que uma nova versão de `meu-pack` seja lançada, a `1.0.1`, e que quebre esta tal compatibilidade com as funções já usadas pelo seu software, a primeira coisa a fazer é congelar a versão no `package.json` na versão anterior.

```
npm i meu-pack@1.0.0 --save-exact
```

Esse comando vai salvar a versão exata de `meu-pack`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "meu-pack": "1.0.0"
  }
```

Assim, não importa se uma nova versão foi lançada. A versão `1.0.0` será sempre instalada quando alguém rodar `npm install` no diretório do projeto.

### npm lockfiles: package-lock.json e npm-shrinkwrap.json

Congelar a versão de `meu-pack` pode, as vezes, não ser suficiente para produzir o mesmo `node_modules/` em outras instalações.

Por exemplo: O pacote `meu-pack` pode ter uma dependência `minha-lib` declarada com o operador `^`, que aceita novas versões em uma nova instalação.

Como, então, garantir que as versões dos pacotes (e das dependências) será exatamente igual no servidor de produção?

Antes que você decida versionar o diretório `node_modules/` no seu repositório, conheça os [*package locks*](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks).

Sempre que rodar `npm install --save` para instalar qualquer pacote, o `npm` vai gerar ou atualizar o arquivo `package-lock.json`, listando a versão exata de todos os pacotes usados pelo projeto, incluindo também as dependências.

### npm shrinkwrap

Shrinkwrap é o nome deste mecanismo antes do `npm@5`, e ele ainda é usado quando você pretende publicar um pacote no registro do npm.

O npm impõe que o arquivo `package-lock.json` nunca seja publicado.

Embora ambos tenham o mesmo formato, o quando `npm-shrinkwrap.json` está presente, ele é usado no lugar do `package-lock.json`.

Você gera `npm-shrinkwrap.json` rodando `npm shrinkwrap`, que apenas renomeia o seu `package-lock.json` para `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.